# How to collect HTTP requests

Tags: java, http, post, get, request

I need to populate a database with the fields of the HTTP requests based on if the sender IP is valid or not.
For example if someone make a GET request on my IP with that:

```
/test/demo.php?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

How can I receive it so I can handle it and perform actions like:

- Get the ip of the sender (And validate it - just confronting it with a list -)
- Recognize the type of the Request
- Extrapolate the fields (value1 and value2) and save them in variables

I'm using java.net.http package

Comment: Is using a framework such as Spring out of the question? There is no need to reinvent the wheel by implementing everything from 0.

Comment: I've actually thought to upgrade to project to Spring, but I'm new to that and asked this question only for educational purpose.
Since sending out HTTP GET requests with Java is really simple I'd like to learn the "raw" way to solve this problem before diving in a framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform that using package `java.net.http` because you need to create an http server not an http client. To achieve that, you need `HttpServer` which is found in package `com.sun.net.httpserver`.

The first thing is to create a new instance of HttpServer :

```
final int port = 3000;//You can change with your port number you need
final HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
System.out.println("Listening port : " + port);
```

Then, configure an http context. The first parameter accepts the route you defines and the second parameter accepts the http handler in which you can extract all your data that you need to store in your database.

```
httpServer.createContext("/test/demo.php", buildHttpHandler());//buildHttpHandler is to create
```

What contains the function `buildHttpHandler()`? :

Each time where route `/test/demo.php` is called, the content of arrow function is called. Here, we attempt only to create a simple page html and serves it to the http client. But before responding http client, we need to extract all data you need (ip, request type and parameters).

```
return httpExchange -> {
    final String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "   <head>\n" +
            "      <title>Page</title>\n" +
            "      <meta charset='utf-8'/>\n" +
            "   </head>\n" +
            "   <body>Ok</body>\n" +
            "</html>";

    //Function to create
    extractData(httpExchange);

    httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, html.length());

    final OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
    outputStream.write(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    outputStream.close();
};
```

What contains `extractData()` function?

In this function we will extract the data you need.

```
final String ip = getClientIp(httpExchange);
System.out.println("IP : " + ip);

final String requestType = httpExchange.getRequestMethod();
System.out.println("Request type : " + requestType);

final Map<String, String> parameters = extractParameters(httpExchange);
displayParameters(parameters);
```

Extracting ip client is more complicated because sometime client uses proxy that's why we create a dedicated function `getClientIp()` to extract the ip.

In this function, we attempt to extract firstly proxy ip. If not found, we extract standard ip from remote :

```
final String ip = getProxyIp(httpExchange);
return ip == null ? httpExchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress() : ip;
```

To extract proxy ip, we create another function `getProxyIp()`. It attempts to extract the ip provided from `x-forwarded-for` request header.

```
final List<String> ips = httpExchange.getRequestHeaders().get("x-forwarded-for");
return ips == null ? null : ips.get(ips.size() - 1);
```

I don't know what do you mean with extrapolating fields but you can store all data in a Map variable. The key will be the name of parameter and the value will be the value of parameter. But this is complicated also because we need to parse the string value from `name1=value1&name2=value2`. So, we create a new function `extractParameters()`. It contains :

```
final String query = httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery();
final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
if (query != null) {
    final String[] firstParts = query.split("&");
    for (final String firstPart : firstParts) {
        final String[] secondParts = firstPart.split("=");
        final String name = secondParts[0];
        final String value = secondParts.length > 1 ? secondParts[1] : null;
        parameters.put(name, value);
    }
}

return parameters;
```

You notice maybe what is `displayParameters()` content. It just attempts to display, parameters retrieved from `extractParameters()`.

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> parameter : parameters.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Parameter key : " + parameter.getKey());
    System.out.println("Parameter value : " + parameter.getValue());
}
```

And finally don't forget to start the http server :

```
httpServer.start();
```

You can check for a full code here https://gist.github.com/razafinarivohanania/24fe0986ea5868097404f2a758131823

When you test it, you can get something like :

```
IP : 127.0.0.1
Request type : GET
Parameter key : name2
Parameter value : value2
Parameter key : name1
Parameter value : value1
```